# Can software recommendation still be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

I need a free vpn that works on Ubuntu 16.04 and connects to UK. The old questions about that subject are obsolete.

I'd like to ask the question on this site, since it has a big community, definitely bigger than software recommendations.

Would my question be accepted here or will it be closed as too broad and told to ask on the other site? [There is a software recommendation tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) and I used to use it long ago, not sure if I can do that still or if it exists as a legacy tag.

Comment: Related: [Should the \[software-recommendation\] tag be deprecated?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/18073)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This tag is in use and fully on topic, but remember your question should be specific and clear, see the [software-recommendation tag info](https://askubuntu.com/tags/software-recommendation/info):

> Questions asking for specific applications that perform a given task
>   or work with a given file format. Give details about the **purpose**
>   of the software you want and your minimum **requirements** for it.
>
> You know what you want to do, and you need help finding an application
>   you can run on Ubuntu that will help you achieve it.
>
> When asking for software recommendations, please be detailed and
>   specific about what you want the software to do. At a minimum, it is
>   helpful to give
>
> - your use case
> - what features are required
>
> Stack Exchange has a
>   dedicated [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site and a [meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) there gives
>   further guidance on how to ask for software recommendations
>   effectively.